# Issue with loading some of the classes using classloader with Install4j app on Mac

Tags: install4j

We are facing some weird issue on MAC with install4j app. Here all the classes in a particular jar are getting loaded except a particular class which is causing application launch failure. Please suggest if you have come across such issue on Mac. But in the log there is no exception or error reported.

There is no issue with directly executing the jar or through eclipse.

Comment: How do you know which class this is if you do not get any error message?

Comment: The issue is fixed now. One of the classes was present twice in the two different jars which were making the issue. After removing the obsolete one the problem got solved. Thanks>